# The height of the HTML tag is set differently than my intention

Tags: html

my structure is

```
table
 ㄴ tbody
    ㄴ tr
       ㄴ td height: 25px
          ㄴ div height:24px
              ㄴ div height: 100%   => why 30px ????
```

Why do I get a 30px when I set the height of the last div to 100%?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer your question. Perhaps you could include a code snippet demonstrating the problem you're running into?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: That code tells everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is that your `<td>` element has padding or border that is inhibiting your `<div>` elements' height. Try setting this CSS up:

```
td {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

It should hopefully fix your code.

Comment if you have any questions or need an explanation.

Comment: Elsewhere I found a place where padding and margin were applied and solved. Thank you.

Comment: No worries! I'm always glad to help people.